# Why can't V8 optimize try-catch-finally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Why is it that V8 is unable to optimize try-catch-finally blocks, when other prominent runtimes (SpiderMonkey, Chakra) seem to have no problems with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no particular reason other than the issue has a relatively low priority.

This will be optimized at some point

Check this out 
[chromium v8 issue 1065](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1065&q=try%20catch&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20HW%20OS%20Component%20Stars)

If you target v8 you can move try-catch to separate function, but you should do this only if it's a real performance issue otherwise its just premature optimization.

> "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or
>   worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and
>   these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact
>   when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about
>   small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization
>   is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities
>   in that critical 3%" -  Donald Knuth

The only function that most likely will never be optimized are

- Functions with a "debugger" statement
- Functions that call eval()
- Functions that contain a "with" statement

Other issues with optimization should be fixed at some point.

Comment: As a late follow-up to this answer, it should be noted that the new TurboFan compiler in V8 now optimizes both try-catch-finally as well as other features: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12178856