# How much slower will try/catch be in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, exception

I have a function that is called every frame and needs to finish within 16ms (sometimes it doesn't even manage). My team was dealing with occasional exceptions to this method, and I wanted to wrap it in try/catch.

I am trying to understand the performance implication here better, as there doesn't seem to be great resources online describing in which situations, or how much, this will degrade performance. I found a very old [blog post](https://modernweb.com/rethinking-javascripts-trycatch/) claiming that the window error event will be more performant way of dealing with the situation.

Could anyone here share some knowledge on this topic, and/or benchmarks?

Comment: Well `try / catch` makes it hard for the optimizer to do its work. It depends on the runtime. You did not post any code, however, and specifics are important.

Comment: And I seriously doubt that using `window.onerror()` would improve performance. Best thing is to have the code not throw exceptions (except in truly exceptional circumstances).

Comment: @Pointy in this case, we want to catch exceptions because of bugs, not because of intentional throws. Also, could you elaborate on why you are sceptical that `window.onerror` would not improve the situation?

Comment: Well the global error handling mechanism is a pretty broad thing. And like I said, if your exceptions are due to bugs, my opinion is that fixing the bugs is more important than an exception handling architecture. Using simple try/catch while you get the bugs fixed is probably the simplest thing.

Comment: @Pointy in order to catch the bugs in the wild, we want to rely on try/catch so that we can have monitoring tools to fix issues if they appear. If we did not do that we wouldn't be able to know if we have bugs in the first place. The internet is a pretty diverse place and there are many types of devices and situations that will end up throwing in unexpected places. It's not really a matter of "fixing the bugs and then removing try/catch". It is a about a long term solution and monitoring the quality of a large-scale product

Comment: if you want to know how much performant something is - measure it!

Comment: Perhaps put a NEW question up with the faulty function and any details that are known such as how it is called, any clues on the exception(s) etc.  You might also add "how can I test this" as a bonus.  You might also delve into how a large function might be broken down into testable parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That article is from 2013](http://ryanmorr.com/reinventing-the-try-catch-block/) and totally outdated. Ten years is an eon in the fast-moving web.

> What makes this construct unique is in the manner in which the catch
> block augments the scope chain. Rather than creating a new execution
> context and pushing it to the top of the execution stack, the `catch`
> block will actually create a new variable object and place it ahead of
> the activation object in the scope chain of the current execution
> context. This creates what is known as a dynamic scope, similar to the
> effect of the `with` statement, which lends to its bad reputation as
> well. As a result, the error object passed to the `catch` block does not
> exist outside of it, even within the same scope. It is created at the
> start of the `catch` clause and destroyed at the end of it. This type of
> manipulation of the scope chain is the primary reason for the
> performance hit.

That is no longer true since ES6 introduced block scopes. Previously, [`catch` blocks were kind of exceptional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15035083/1048572), but still they would only introduce a nested scope, not have a dynamic scope with arbitrary names like the `with` statement, so that comparison never held up.

Since lexical scoping was introduced, it quickly became common and is now as well optimised as anything else.

> At this point you may be thinking that as long as an error is not
> raised than performance should not be affected. That is a fair
> assumption, but you’d be wrong. Some JavaScript engines, such as V8
> (Chrome) do not optimize functions that make use of a `try`/`catch` block
> as the optimizing compiler will skip it when encountered. No matter
> what context you use a `try`/`catch` block in, there will always be an
> inherent performance hit, quite possibly a substantial one.

There is [a bit of truth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38121208/1048572) in that, but this [quickly became outdated](https://v8.dev/blog/high-performance-es2015#a-modern-architecture-for-a-modern-language) with [new optimising compilers](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan) in 2017.